# SQL Server TDE encryption

Tags: sql-server-2017, tde

The question is one of my clients ask whether they can BYOK (Bring your own key). When it comes to that;

1) I couldn't find any detailed information whether we can do it for a locally hosted SQL Server. But it seems possible for Azure SQL DB.

2) Using EKM Provider. Seems like all of them are 3rd party and Windows Server doesn't come with a default provider. Am I correct? I would like to use a EKM provider but don't want to spend more just for a single client. What are the options I have?

Comment: Having examined the EKM provider SDK in detail, I don't believe it is possible to BYOK.

Comment: [NetLib Encryptionizer for SQL Server](https://netlibsecurity.com/products/sql-server-encryption/) let's you BYOK. And it works with all Editions of SQL Server from Express to Enterprise. Disclaimer: I am with NetLib Security.